# How to run a Jupyter notebook inside another

Tags: python, jupyter, nvidia, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a `.ipynb` file inside another.  The reason why I want to nest the two is because in one of them, I have all of the conda packages, github repos installed and I don't want to redo the entire thing for a demo file that I'll be using temporarily.  I'm using colab because my computer does not have an NVIDIA GPU and therefore I can't use CUDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
%run another.ipynb
```

You may need to mount drive to access your `drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/`

Comment: The `ipynb` file was downloaded inside the main Colab notebook.

Comment: Works for me. Here's an example notebook. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1G4kTsJKBLf2lKK6ELFH3B2MFgg9mQgSA